Query plan stage appears to be a bottleneck in mongoid, what am I doing wrong?
I experience problems with query performance in Mongoid.
The major part of time is taken by query plan but not query itself (the relation is 5-to-1) and this is not being changed after a number of requests.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-plans/
My expectations
DB should not spend that much time on analyze phase. Imo it never should be a bottleneck - no matter how bad my indexes are.
I expect mongo to adjust itself after several requests but it's not.
Details
The query I am talking about is on big collection with big skip. Nevertheless I can see no reason why query plan works that strange: it seems like DB just not cache plan analyze results and perform it every request.
Environment:

rails (7.0.8.1);
mongo (2.15.1);
mongoid (7.5.4).
Mongo DB (same problems on 3.4.15 and 4.4.10)

Questions

Why it continues to take that much time on query plan in every request?

Does Mongoid have query plan cache functionality at all? If so:
a) why am I experiencing such DB behaviour?
b) does it have any API and where can I find any docs describing that? E.g. is there any way I can configure query cache plan in Mongoid anyhow (check query plan cache or clear it)?


UPDATE-1 (adding details of my query)
Query:
.find("is_visible"=>true, 
      "published_at"=>{"$lt"=>Time.current}, 
      "topic_type"=>{"$in"=>["article", "card", "daily_photo", "event", "gallery", "game_compare", "horoscope", "news", "opinion", "pair_compare", "product", "quiz", "specproject", "star", "ugc", "video"]}, 
      "authors.slug"=>"novostnaya-sluzhba")
.sort("published_at"=>-1)
.projection("link"=>1, "headline"=>1, "list_headline"=>1, "comments_count"=>1, "published_at"=>1, "image"=>1, "rubric"=>1)
.skip(50000)
.limit(10)

Index I expect to be used:
authors.slug_1_topic_type_1_is_visible_1_published_at_-1
Explain:

skip(30000) (my index automatically chosen)

skip(50000) (my index never automatically chosen)

skip(50000) with index .hint (x60 faster than previous query)


As I see the problem is that during query planning (allPlansExecution) it tries to examine too many keys (totalKeysExamined) - same as real query does - which leads to unreasonable big timing for analyze stage. Another strange thing is that with bigger skip my index is not being used anymore.
